# How to make sure in a parameter grid search, every sample must have a fix value

Tags: python, grid-search

I have a parameter grid and  I draw some samples from it.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid, ParameterSampler
import numpy as np

grid = {'a': np.linspace(1, 10, 10),
        'b': np.linspace(1, 5, 5),
        'c': ['str1', 'str2'],
        'd': ['model1', 'model2']
        }

n_combinations = ParameterGrid(grid).__len__()
# 50 % of possible combinations
samples = ParameterSampler(grid, random_state=1,
                           n_iter=int(0.5*n_combinations))
```

I want to make sure that for any combination of 'a', 'b' and 'c' should have 'd' ='model1' and the same values 'a', 'b' and 'c' with 'd' = 'model2'.

For instance, for `a=1, b=2, c='str2'`

The combinations should be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b':2, c:'str2', d='model1'}  # and
{'a': 1, 'b':2, c:'str2', d='model2'}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is: since I draw (randomly) some samples from the total number of possible combinations among 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd',  very few of those samples match my requirement of having the same  values for 'a', 'b' and 'c' with 'd'='model1' and other sample with  'd'='model2', and that is what I want to make sure (if possible): for a random choice of 'a', 'b' and 'c' make a combination that includes 'd'='model1' and another one with 'd'='model2'.